# how to generate three address code for array static initialize and struct for c-like language

Tags: compiler-construction

im writting a program to generate three address code for c-like language,but how to generate TAC like following code:

int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
struct str = {"name","age",123};

i find many related resourece,but they doesn't mention that

Comment: If arr and str are global (or static) variables, then there is no code generation involved. The initialization routine generates initialized data in that case. If arr and str are local variables then the initialization routine generates code. The generated code is not much different from regular assignments.

Comment: im really appreciate your explain ,you mean that what i need to do is just allocate correspond memory and record them rather than generate code to global variables.but if it is local variables,how to do that?same approach or not?@urutech

Comment: For local variables, you generate code as if this would be assignments such as arr[0]=1; arr[1]=2; etc..